# Broken D3 Visualization in Edge

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, colors, cross-browser

I have D3 visualization that works in Chrome and Safari fine, it's online here:
https://bl.ocks.org/KingOfCramers/04fe907049ec89c680f4fd8839e7ed0a

It looks like this:

[image]

However, when I checked it in Edge and Firefox it gives me a strange color for a specific number of the countries:

[image]

Why is that the case? Are some browsers able to handle different colors? If so, how can I know which colors are appropriate for different browsers, or which ones I should avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redScale (color) range is missing a '#' for **F2D1D4**:

```
.range(["F2D1D4","#D9767E","#D35F69","#CC4954","#BA0514"])
```

Can you try adding that?

```
.range(["#F2D1D4","#D9767E","#D35F69","#CC4954","#BA0514"])
```

Does that fix?

Comment: Yep. Good eyes, thanks. I wouldn't have suspected a typo like that to cause it to break in some browsers and not others. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) I wonder how it works well in Chrome and Safari. I'll inspect it and let you know!

Comment: Don't worry about it, as long as it works it works. Thanks for your help.